# Removing Credits from AnyChart-React

Tags: reactjs, anychart

Removing credits from standard [anycharts](http://www.anychart.com) is well documented [here](https://docs.anychart.com/7.14.0/Quick_Start/Credits#disable):

```js
var credits = chart.credits();
credits.enabled(false);
```

What's the easiest way of going about this with the [AnyChart-React](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-React) library, I can see nothing documented?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use an instance property on AnyChart component - all properties (except of reserved) will be called on chart as if it would be a JS API ([see component usage](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-React#usage)). So if you want to turn credits off, set credits property to false:
`<AnyChart credits={false} />` (equivalent of `chart.credits(false)`)

Comment: Haven't had any luck implementing this, from what I can garner from the docs I need to to add the licence in addition but I haven't had any luck with this: `<Anychart credits={false} licenseKey='MY_LICENCE_HERE' {...{` https://docs.anychart.com/Quick_Start/Credits#license.

Comment: Please add `anychart.licenseKey(yourKey)` before rendering component. For example right after import section, where you include anychart component (`import AnyChart from 'anychart-react'`)

Answer (score 2):

Just put the following into your css:

```
.anychart-credits {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the instance of anychart, and then call credits function, looks like:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const credits = this.anyChart.instance.credits();
  credits.enabled(false);
}
    
render() {
  return <AnyChart ref={(ref) => { this.anyChart = ref; }} />;
}
```

Comment: It's certainly a solution, I was hoping there was a way to do it with a property on the component. Also there would be no way to implement this on a stateless component.

Comment: how about preconfigured instance ? you can configure your credit there. reference :

https://github.com/anychart/anychart-react/blob/master/examples/src/simple_dashboard.js

Answer (score 0):

Thats not so evident and do not explained at docs. I had succesfully set license key and hide credits for AnyChart React component, please see the code below.

```
import React from 'react'

import AnyChart from 'anychart-react'

export class DonutChart extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        window.anychart.licenseKey('YOUR-KEY-HERE')
    }

    render() {
        return(

        <div className="sixteen wide column" style={{ padding: "30px 20px 0px 20px" }}>

            <AnyChart
                type = "pie"
                data = { [1, 2, 3, 4] }
                title = "Simple pie chart"
                credits={false}
            />

        </div>

        )
    }

}

export default DonutChart
```